# Trouble with UIView Constraints

Tags: swift

To start with, here's a mockup of the layout I'm trying to accomplish in Swift. 
[image: Mockup]

And here's what I have so far, 
[image: Error]

So here's the problem. Notice that in the second image the green UIView overflows exceeding the TableViewCell height.

In my Main TableViewController class I've defined each cell to be 120 pixels in height, and the green UIView 10 pixels short of the cell height with the 10 pixels on top as a separator between subsequent cells.

Cell height definition:

```
var itemHeight = [CGFloat](count: 2, repeatedValue: 120.0)
```

UIView constraints:

```
    foregroundView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(foregroundView.superview?.topAnchor, constant: 10).active = true
    foregroundView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(foregroundView.superview?.leftAnchor, constant: 20).active = true
    foregroundView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(foregroundView.superview?.widthAnchor, constant: -40).active = true
    foregroundView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(110).active = true
```

Any ideas on what might be causing the UIView overflow?
Thanks in advance!

**Please let me know if you'd like to see the code in context :)**

Comment: Why don't you use Autolayout to build out cells?

Comment: I could be, but I'd like to know what's behind this issue with the existing code :)

Comment: Can you also share the code where you are adding the foreground view and the other question would be that in which method are you adding the constraints?

Comment: Here's the entire project, if you don't mind: https://mega.nz/#!AJERSbQD!U9rGx1-taAk11jcdpIC_D3y2Es-UpdZv2DGjecYil-A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove two lines of code from your project:

```
foregroundView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

And

```
containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

They are forcing an untimely laying out of content that is causing your problem.

Comment: Removing this snippet of code worked perfectly! As a side question: the function _layoutIfNeeded()_ calls for an immediate reDraw of all views and subviews. You say that the function causes a untimely layout, does that mean that the function is called too early/late or is it rather unnecessary? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When working with table views there is a lot of redrawing going on at different times, reusing cells, etc. So my assumption is that an immediate call to layout part way through the laying out of the entire view and all its components causes the issue. While `setNeedsLayout()` which waits for the next layout cycle would remove the issue actually Auto Layout itself handles this situation and so isn't required.